# to host an application made in xampp using mysql for database and php for front view in my own website

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7, xampp, host

Firstly .let me tell you that i have never hosted any website or application so i am at level zero. I have created an application using xampp server in which mysql is used as the database and php is used for front end. Now i want to access that application from two three other computers connected through lan . So i wanted to get this application and database on my website.So that anyone can access my application by logining in my website. how do i do that? please give me start to end idea about doing this ..a reference or link to a tutorial matching my requirement will be appreciated.And yes my machine has windows -7 in it.

Comment: Find someone that can do that - There's tutorials all over the internet regarding that.

Comment: yes you are correct but i am not getting the one that matches my requirements

Answer (score 0):

Download XAMPP and install it (https://www.apachefriends.org/de/)

Open your browser and go to http://127.0.0.1 to complete the installation

Go to your XAMPP-Install path and into subfolder "htdocs" This is where all the PHP-Scripts lay.

Create a new Subfolder (e.g. test) and inside this folder a file named "index.php". Files of this name are initial files.

```
  <?php
    // Define a variable
    $a = 10;
    // read a variable from URL
    $b = intVal($_GET['input']);
  ?>
  <html>
    <body>
      <form>
        <input type="test" name="input"><br>
        <div><?php echo $a.' + '.$b.' = '.($a+$b) ?></div>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

this is a simple example of a PHP script to play with. You cann call this script from other PC by simply open a Browser and go to http://*IP-Of-Your-PC*/test/

If you have done this start reading PHP-Tutorials and MySql-Tutorials like http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php